# Adding a percentage % sign to an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, percentage, sign

I am configuring a table to import data from a .csv file. sl.name is column 1, sl.asl is column 2, and @"%@ - %@" represents a space dash space in between the two. I need to enter a % directly after the value of sl.asl but cannot get it to work on this string using @"%%" ...possibly because of the existing @"%@ - %@"? I don't know!

```
// Configure the cell...
ServiceLevel *sl = (ServiceLevel *)[self.importedRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@" , sl.name , sl.asl];
```

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@%%", ...]`

Comment: it is the same as a printf format string... %%

Comment: In theory `%%` in a format string gives you a `%` in the final string, but I've had that fail in some cases, and so simply used `%c` and added `'%'` to the parm list.